# Setup/Deployment project: Prevent modified files from being removed when uninstalling

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a setup project. If the user modifies one of the installed files and then un-installs the application, I'd like the file to NOT get deleted by the uninstall (so that when the user re-installs later, the modified file is used rather than the default one that the installer would normally use). Is this at all possible?

Note: Files which have not been edited should be applicable for upgrades/removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not possible to prevent the setup project from removing modified files when uninstalling, the best approach I have found (as mentioned by Ciprian) is to create a custom action which backs up the modified files before uninstallation, and restores them in another custom action afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent uninstall you should mark the files' component as Permanent

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I think they don't want to leave things installed - they just want to leave any user customizations instead of blowing them away.

Comment: That's correct. Files which have not been edited should be applicable for upgrades/removal.

Comment: You should use then some custom actions to back-up the files before the RemoveFiles action and restore then afterwords.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid custom actions but there doesn't seem to be any other way.